# Sufficient conditions for when continuity at a point implies continuity in a neighbourhood of that point

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I know that function $f$ is continuous at some $x_0=(y_0,z_0)$. Are there any other properties of function $f$ that can help me to conclude that function $f$ is in fact continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$? I know, e.g., that function $f(y,z)$ is continuous from the right in $y$ for any $z$ and is continuous from the right in $z$ for any $y$. I also know that $f$ is non-decreasing in each component.

I am not interested in obvious properties that immediately imply the continuity of $f$ everywhere (such as differentiability, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that there is no such condition that doesn't feel unnecessarily strong.

Here are some examples:

1. The function defined by
   $$
   f(y,z)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   0,&z\in\mathbb Q\\
   y,&z\notin\mathbb Q
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is continuous at the origin and continuous in $y$ for any fixed $z$, but it is not continuous in any neighborhood of the origin.
   This does not satisfy your assumptions yet, but it is still a good example to keep in mind.
2. The function defined by
   $$
   f(y,z)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   0,&y\geq0\\
   z,&y<0
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is continuous from the right in $y$ for any fixed $z$ and vice versa and continuous at the origin, but not continuous in any neighborhood of the origin.
3. You can make the previous example non-decreasing in both variables:
   $$
   f(y,z)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   0,&y\geq0\text{ or }z\geq0\\
   z,&y<0\text{ and }z<0
   \end{cases}
   $$

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of such an example. But I was hoping that those extra one-sided continuity properties that I have might help. The example you gave does not satisfy those. I also added monotonicity properties that I have.

Comment: @Alik Sorry! I added another example. It's continuous from the right in both variables. Is that more satisfying?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Alik Turns out there is a counter-example which is non-decreasing in both arguments.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for all your help!